# If $\frac {1}{2+a} + \frac {1}{2+b} + \frac {1}{2+c} = 1$, prove $\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{ac} + \sqrt{bc} \leq 3$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, fractions, substitution, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be non-negative numbers such that $$\frac {1}{2+a} + \frac {1}{2+b} + \frac {1}{2+c} = 1.$$

Prove that $ \sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{ac} + \sqrt{bc} \leq 3 $.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2+a}+\frac{1}{2+b}+\frac{1}{2+c}=1$ is equivalent to $ab+bc+ca+abc=4$. Multiply both sides by $(2+a)(2+b)(2+c)$. [See WolframAlpha if you don't want to do it yourself.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%2Ba)(2%2Bb)(2%2Bc)+-+(1%2F(2%2Ba)+%2B+1%2F(2%2Bb)+%2B+1%2F(2%2Bc))(2%2Ba)(2%2Bb)(2%2Bc)) Therefore this question is the same as this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472959/if-abbccaabc-4-then-sqrtab-sqrtbc-sqrtac-leq3-via-am-gm

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461934/inequalities-contest-math

Answer (score 8):

The condition gives:
$$\frac32-1 = \sum_{cyc} \left(\frac12-\frac1{2+a} \right)$$
$$\implies 1 = \sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{2+a} \ge \frac{(\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c)^2}{a+b+c+6} \quad \text{by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality}$$
$$\implies 3 \ge \sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}$$

Comment: maybe $\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{ac} + \sqrt{bc} \le a+b+c\leq 3$more straightforward.

Comment: @chenbai But $a+b+c\geq 3$.

Comment: Looks OK now, +1. Maybe the first inequality could use some extra explanation.

Comment: @Dr.MV The intention is not to spell out every detail, however you may note that the "last" inequality follows from simplification (cross multiply, expand, cancel) of the "first" inequality.

Comment: Macavity.  Yes, I understand.  Actually, my request was meant only as a suggestion to assist other potential readers that might not have your level of mathematical maturity.  I might have shown, for example, that Cauchy-Schwartz, as it is usually expressed (i.e., $||x||^2||y||^2\ge\left(<x,y>\right)^2$), can be modified easily by letting $x=\sqrt(\frac{u}{v})$ and $y=\sqrt(v)$.

Comment: @Dr.MV You need to put an "@" sign before the user name if someone is to get your message! On the other points, I have seen Cauchy Schwarz written in the inner product form (which you mention) as well as in many other forms almost as frequently, including the $\mathbb R^n$ version and the so called "Titu's lemma".  Normally I would respond if someone has a specific question, rather than try anticipating what is "usual" for the diverse audience we have here.

Comment: @Macavity  Thanks for the tip on the use of the "@" symbol.  The person who posted the question is presumably new to the site and might not have attained the level of mathematical maturity that you have.  If the goal is to help, then my belief is to add more information than less.  The fundamental form for the C_S that is seen most often is expressed something like $\sum x_n^2 \sum y_n^2 \ge (\sum x_ny_n)^2$ or $\int f^2 dx \int g^2 dx \ge (\int fg dx)^2$, etc.  Your proof was awesome by the way!

Comment: @Dr.MV Hope you start using the tip.  Personally I believe people develop better by trying to solve rather than by reading detailed solutions. I would consider following the second approach if the OP stated in follow up that form was what he/she was familiar with - rather than guess or take an opinion poll on the subject. At present, it is not even clear the person knows what CS inequality is, and I have no intention of starting from basic axioms.

Comment: @chenbai See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461934/inequalities-contest-math for why $a+b+c\ge 3$.

Answer (score 2):

The condition gives that there are $\alpha\geq0$, $\beta\geq0$ and $\gamma\geq0$ such that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$ for which $\sqrt{ab}=2\cos\gamma$, $\sqrt{ac}=2\cos\beta$ and $\sqrt{bc}=2\cos\alpha$.

Hence, we need to prove that $\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma\leq\frac{3}{2}$, which is obvious.

Comment: If $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $gamma$ are real numbers, then have you not restricted the range of values for $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Comment: it must be $\cos(\alpha),\cos(\beta),\cos(\gamma)\geq 0$

Comment: To   Dr. MV. The condition gives $4=ab+ac+bc+abc$. Id est, $\sqrt{ab}\leq2$, $\sqrt{ac}\leq2$ and $\sqrt{bc}\leq2$.

Comment: Michael Rozenberg.  How did you arrive at your conclusions?  The approach is not obvious to all.

Comment: Dr.MV. Let $\sqrt{ab}=2\cos\gamma$, $\sqrt{ac}=2\cos\beta$, where $\{\beta,\gamma\}\subset[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $\sqrt{bc}=2x$. 
Hence, $x^2+2\cos\beta\cos\gamma x+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma-1=0$. 
Thus, $x=-\cos\beta\cos\gamma+\sqrt{\cos^2\beta\cos^2\gamma-\cos^2\beta-\cos^2\gamma+1}$ or
$x=-\cos\beta\cos\gamma+\sin\beta\sin\gamma$ or $x=\cos(\pi-\beta-\gamma)$.
Let  $\pi-\beta-\gamma=\alpha$ and we are ready to use $\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma\leq\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Michael Rozenberg. You start with an assumption that (  √ ab)≤2  and (  √ ac)≤2 . How does one know this a priori, without proving that which is to be shown? You stated in a previous comment that you "est" this. That isn't rigorous, is it? How would the results be different if one assumes that these upper bounds are, for example, 1 , 2.5 , or even 5 , instead of 2 ?  Finally, how is it obvious that the sum of the 3 cosine terms is less than 3/2?  It is obvious that their sum is less than 3.  What are you using to give the tighter bound?

Comment: @Mark Viola The condition gives $ab+ac+bc+abc=4$ and from here $\sqrt{ab}\leq2$.

Comment: You waited more than 2 years to reply.  Why now?

Comment: @Mark Viola Because I did not see it before. I am sorry!

Comment: No worry. And thank you.