# If $ab+bc+ca+abc=4$ then $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}\leq3$, via AM-GM

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Suppose, for positive reals $a$, $b$, $c$, that
>   $$ab+bc+ca+abc=4$$
>   Prove that 
>   $$\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}\leq3$$

I applied AM-GM on the first equality ie, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $abc$ to get $$ab+bc+ca \geq 3\qquad\text{and}\qquad abc \leq1$$

The exact equation is as follows

$$1=\frac{ab+bc+ca+abc}{4}\ge\sqrt[4]{(abc)^3}\implies 1\ge abc$$

However, I didn't manage to get any further than this after applying AM-GM to several other inequalities.

I'd like a solution for this that utilizes AM-GM only, as I'm very new to inequalities.

Comment: Something is missing. If $a=b=c=-2$ the assumption $ab+bc+ca+abc=4$ holds, but the sum of those square roots is $6>3$. Did you forget to include the assumption that $a,b,c$ are positive? Exactly how did you apply AM-GM to the equation? Or, is something else missing given that you refer to *the first inequality*.

Comment: i forgot to write abc are positive reals and i meant first equality.

Comment: If the condition is $ab+bc+ca=\mbox{const}$, the function $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}$ has a maximum. If the condition is $abc=\mbox{const}$, the function has a minimum. How do AM-GM equations know at what combination coefficients the minimum-maximum sign changes?

Comment: It's the same as this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180443/any-idea-proving-inequality, just the condition is written differently.

Comment: For contest math that means a completely different trick is required. As in my point, even a change of the coefficients would mean a completely different problem.

Comment: I don't know if it helps to use $x=\sqrt{ab}$, $y=\sqrt{bc}$, $z=\sqrt{ac}$ to rewrite the problem as maximizing $x+y+z$ subject to $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$.

Comment: Ive added on exactly how ive used AM GM

Comment: @Zhouran He so any ideas?

Comment: Also a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461934/inequalities-contest-math

Comment: @user236182, how did you find it? Once there are expressions in the title, searching becomes very difficult.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe I found it in Related questions on the right. I clicked on questions that have no math expressions in the title and found it.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe I've edited the title.

Comment: My linked question was posted one week ago.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=\frac{2x}{y+z}$ and $b=\frac{2y}{x+z}$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positives.

Thus, the condition gives
$$\frac{4xy}{(x+z)(y+z)}+2c\left(\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{x+z}\right)+\frac{4xyc}{(x+z)(y+z)}=4$$ or
$$\frac{2c(x^2+y^2+xz+yz+2xy)}{(x+z)(y+z)}=4-\frac{4xy}{(x+z)(y+z)}$$ or
$$\frac{2c(x+y)(x+y+z)}{(x+z)(y+z)}=\frac{4z(x+y+z)}{(x+z)(y+z)}$$ or
$$c=\frac{2z}{x+y}$$ and we need to prove that
$$2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{xy}{(x+z)(y+z)}}\leq3, $$
which is AM-GM:
$$2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{xy}{(x+z)(y+z)}}\leq\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x}{x+z}+\frac{y}{y+z}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x}{x+z}+\frac{z}{z+x}\right)=3. $$
Done!

There are proofs by trigonometry and $uvw$ but they are not easy.

Comment: How can you assume them as sharing the same variable......

Comment: That's the trick. The constraint $ab+bc+ac+abc=4$ is equivalent to $a=2x/(y+z)$, $b=2y/(x+z)$, $c=2z/(x+y)$ for arbitrary $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^+$. One degree of freedom is lost because rescaling $x,y,z$ by the same factor does not affect $a,b,c$. So the trick does not generalize to e.g. $2(ab+bc+ac)+abc=7$?

Comment: @Zhuoran Yes it does not work for your condition. But we can use another methods. We can use the contradiction method, for example.

Comment: I dont get it is there a simpler method.

Comment: @John Doe 1234 What is your question. I am ready to explain. All other methods, which I see they are harder.

Comment: Okay so, first how did you assume x,y,z to be the same for all of abc?

Comment: also how do those cyclic inequalities add up

Comment: @JohnDoe1234 Here's a rigorous proof that you can assume that $a=\frac{2x}{y+z}$, $b=\frac{2y}{x+z}$, where $x,y,z>0$. After that from $ab+bc+ca+abc=4$ it follows that $c=\frac{2z}{x+y}$. Proof: let $x'=\frac{x}{z}$, $y'=\frac{y}{z}$. You want to prove that there exist $x',y'>0$ such that $a=\frac{2x'}{y'+1}$, $b=\frac{2y'}{x'+1}$. First I will tell you how I found this proof and later I will give you the final rigorous proof. Rearrange the first equation $a=\frac{2x'}{y'+1}$ to get $y'=\frac{2x'-a}{a}$. Put this expression of $y'$ into $b=\frac{2y'}{x'+1}$ and get $x'=\frac{a(b+2)}{4-ab}$.

Comment: @JohnDoe1234 We have $4-ab>0$ proof: if $ab\ge 4$, then $ab+bc+ca+abc>4+0+0+0=4$, contradiction. Put this expression of $x'$ into $y'=\frac{2x'-a}{a}$ and you'll get $y'=\frac{b(a+2)}{4-ab}$. Final rigorous proof: let $x'=\frac{a(b+2)}{4-ab}$, $y'=\frac{b(a+2)}{4-ab}$, where we must have $4-ab>0$, etc. because $ab+bc+ca+abc=4$ and $a,b,c>0$. Then $a=\frac{2x'}{y'+1}$, $b=\frac{2y'}{x'+1}$, equivalently $a=\frac{2x}{y+z}$, $b=\frac{2y}{x+z}$.

Comment: @JohnDoe1234 $$\sum_{\text{cyc}}\left(\frac{x}{x+z}+\frac{y}{y+z}\right)=\frac{x}{x+z}+\frac{y}{y+z}+$$

$$+\frac{y}{y+x}+\frac{z}{z+x}+\frac{z}{z+y}+\frac{x}{x+y}=$$

$$=\left(\frac{x}{x+y}+\frac{y}{y+x}\right)+\left(\frac{y}{y+z}+\frac{z}{z+y}\right)+$$

$$+\left(\frac{z}{z+x}+\frac{x}{x+z}\right)=(1)+(1)+(1)=3$$

Comment: @user236182 Thank you for your work!

Comment: @JohnDoe1234 I added something. See now.